# Why "git clone" when I can do the same with "git pull" after "git init"?

Tags: git

I have created a git repository using `git init` and added a remote repo URL by using `git remote add origin https://remote-url`

When I did `git pull origin master` after setting up the necessary upstream branch by using `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` to track remote branch (my local master branch was set to track the remote master branch this after doing `git checkout master`), I am able to pull all the revision history of my remote project branch into my local repo.

If I can very well do this with `git pull`, then why **git** provides `git clone` as a separate command and an alternative? Does it serve any special purpose or do I miss anything by doing `git pull` alone?

Comment: It would be rather hostile if it *required* these gymnastics every time you wanted to clone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not an unreasonable question.  But so is this one:

You can run:

```
git write-tree
git commit-tree -p HEAD -m message <hash-from-git-write-tree>
git branch -f <current-branch> <hash-from-git-commit-tree>
```

This does the same thing—well, it does if there are no errors—as:

```
git commit -m message
```

so why do we have a `git commit` command at all?

Here's a followup question: Which of these is easier to use?

---

The `git clone` command is actually equivalent to running up to *six* commands, five of which are Git commands.  The six steps involved in `git clone` are:

1. `mkdir path`, to make a new empty directory in which to run `git init`.  (This step is skipped in the special case in which you give `git clone` the path name of an existing but empty directory, in which case it uses that.)
2. `git init`, to create a new empty repository in the new directory.
3. `git remote add remote url`, where *`remote`* is from your `git clone` option `-o`, or is `origin` if you did not specify this option, and the *`url`* is the one you specified in the clone command.
4. Any additional `git config` commands from options supplied to `git clone`.
5. `git fetch remote`, to obtain commits from the Git at the supplied URL.
6. `git checkout branch`, where the *`branch`* is the one you specified with the `-b` option in your `git clone` command, or a branch specified by the *other* Git if you did not specify a branch, or `master` if the other Git does not specify any branch.

The `git clone` command also handles various errors that can occur during this process that you would otherwise have to handle yourself.

---

The `git pull` command is equivalent to running `git fetch` followed by a second Git command.  That second command is usually `git merge`, though you can tell Git to use `git rebase`instead.  But `git pull` has one more special mode: when you `git pull` into a completely empty repository, as you did in your question, it can run `git checkout` as its second command instead of either of the other two.

---

Note: unlike `git clone`, where it's very rare to need anything *between* the six steps, with `git pull` it's pretty common for *me* to need to *inspect the commits that `git fetch` obtained* before I run a second command.  So I generally avoid `git pull` entirely, because it forces me to choose the second command to run, and to run it immediately upon the completion of the fetch step, when I would like to do something else after fetch, *before* I choose whether to use merge, or rebase, or something else entirely.